# What is the best approach to make android apps?

Tags: android

I was just reading a tutorial at

http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/android/Android-Programming-Basics.pdf

It has 3 ways in which android applications can be build

**• Java-based**

- Use Java to define Strings, lay out window, create GUI 
  controls, and assign event handlers. Like Swing programming.

**• XML-based**

- Use XML files to define Strings, lay out window, create GUI 
  controls, and assign event handlers. The Java method will read 
  the the layout from XML file and pass it to setContentView layout from XML file and pass it to setContentView.

**• Hybrid**

- Use an XML file to define Strings, lay out window and create 
  GUI controls. Use Java to assign event handlers

*I was wondering if I can know which is the best way to go especially if project is small or big?*

Comment: so after reading this you think that it is possible to build android application with only xml files? ... you can only assign onClick event from xml, so "XML-based" approach doen't exits ... read http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html

Comment: No real question here? XML-only is impossibru, java-only isn't advised (define your strings in XML, etc). It's about 2 extremes and "something in between". Obviously you'll land somewhere in between :)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the apps need Hybrid approach. You define layouts in XML, activities using Java. Sometimes even you may end up coding UI in Java. So, I would vote for Hybrid approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the hybrid approach, as that is the approach used in the eclipse IDE, which android favours you use when making apps.